# Why does Log4J2 output differ on two systems when I am writing the same UTF-8?

Tags: java, logging, utf-8, log4j2, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm writing Unicode characters to a Log4J2 log.  On one machine (Windows 8) I see this in the log:

```
2016-08-30 16:44:00.958|English:  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
2016-08-30 16:44:00.960|German:  Falsches Üben von Xylophonmusik quält jeden größeren Zwerg.
2016-08-30 16:44:00.960|Russian 1:  В чащах юга жил бы цитрус? Да, но фальшивый экземпляр!
2016-08-30 16:44:00.960|Russian 2:  Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю.
2016-08-30 16:44:00.960|Chinese:  中国智造，慧及全球
2016-08-30 16:44:00.960|Japanese:  いろはにほへと ちりぬるを わかよたれそ つねならむ うゐのおくやま けふこえて あさきゆめみし ゑひもせす
2016-08-30 16:44:00.960|Korean:  다람쥐 헌 쳇바퀴에 타고파
```

On another machine (Windows Server 2012R2) I see this:

```
2016-08-30 16:50:41.676|English:  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
2016-08-30 16:50:41.676|German:  Falsches Üben von Xylophonmusik quält jeden größeren Zwerg.
2016-08-30 16:50:41.676|Russian 1:  ? ????? ??? ??? ?? ??????? ??, ?? ????????? ?????????!
2016-08-30 16:50:41.676|Russian 2:  ????? ?? ??? ???? ?????? ??????????? ????? ?? ????? ???.
2016-08-30 16:50:41.676|Chinese:  ?????????
2016-08-30 16:50:41.676|Japanese:  ??????? ????? ?????? ????? ??????? ????? ??????? ?????
2016-08-30 16:50:41.676|Korean:  ??? ? ???? ???
```

If Log4J2 writes UTF-8 by default, why does the log file on the 2nd system contain only question marks?  That is, the second system *may* (and probably *is*) missing fonts, but the log file itself on the 2nd system contains actual question marks when, using a hexdump tool, I would expect to see at least the binary for the UTF-8 characters in the file.  Put another way, I can understand why an unknown character might *render* incorrectly, I just don't understand why the correct Unicode was not written to the file, if the process doing the writing is the JVM, which uses Unicode for characters.

Comment: How did you specify to Log4j to use UTF-8?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you try to enforce the UTF-8 charset for your Log4j Layout, inside your Log4j configuration file? For example, using `PatternLayout`:

```
<Configuration ...>
    ...
    <PatternLayout pattern="..." charset="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</Configuration>
```

See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html for more information on Log4j encoding issues.

Answer (score 4):

The default charset for the pattern layout in Log4j 2 is the system default charset, not UTF8. Other layouts may have a different default charset, this is documented in the [manual page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) for each layout.

As indicated in the other answer, you can specify the charset in the layout's configuration.

Comment: If you don't read thoroughly like me, you might have read only the top of the page "The root class for layouts that use a Charset is org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout where the default is UTF-8." but if you keep reading to the Pattern Layout section it says "charset: The character set to use when converting the syslog String to a byte array. The String must be a valid Charset. If not specified, this layout uses the platform default character set."